# How to push code-review label on Gerrit onbehalf of other User

Tags: python, rest, gerrit

I am trying to push code review +1 using 'on_behalf_of' in the Body long with Label field. but i am getting response code 403, it giving below response message

Response:
'not permitted to modify label "Code-Review" on behalf of ""

below is my post body
URL:- 'http:///base-url/changes//revisions/current/review'
data: {'on_behalf_of': 'user-name@mail.com', 'labels': {'Code-Review': 1}}

User-name is Service account or faceless ID, I don't have credential of it.
Can anyone suggest  how to push code-review using Group/Service-account id? where do we get the permission for this post?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the "Label Code-Review (On Behalf Of)" permission to be able to review on behalf of someone.

See the "on_behalf_of" item in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#set-review).

Comment: Hi Marcelo,on_behalf_of
from the link https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#review-input 
 optional

{account-id} the review should be posted on behalf of. To use this option the caller must have been granted labelAs-NAME permission for all keys of labels.   How to get LabelAs-NAME permission for all keys

Comment: I think the documentation means "for all keys of labels THAT YOU WANT TO REVIEW", in your case just Code-Review (On Behalf Of) -1 to 1 (or -2 to 2).

Comment: marceto, instead of on-behalf , i used script to be executed directly on Jenkins job without giving on-behalf as in job we have user credential configure.

Answer (score 0):

To isolate all permission issues:

Apart from the command executer is having "Label Code-Review (On Behalf Of)" permission, the user in the context of 'on_behalf_of' should have permission to vote for Code-Review.